# Azure API Management - Cache key uniqueness

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Must a cache key be globally unique within your APIM instance? Or only unique within an API?

Answer (score 0):

> Must a cache key be globally unique within your APIM instance? Or only unique within an API?

It is only unique within an API.

Cache key elements combined to `specify a unique identifier for cache entries`. So it use unique cache key to distinguish with other cache entries. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/working-cachekeys).

Comment: Hm, so one API can overwrite the cache in another API within the same APIM instance? That doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: I have update my reply, you could refer to. If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Comment: Actually, I just confirmed you can get AND set cache values from one API to another. So, not only do they have to be globally unique, they can be globally modified as well... yikes.